# JqueryUI opener on append

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, append

i have this jqueriUI dialog:

```
    <script>
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });

    $( "#opener_0" ).click(function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
  });
  </script>
```

and this is how i draw the buttons (it will be more thank one dialog):

```
for (r=0;r<array[i];r++){
            $('#list').append('<button id="opener_' + r + '">Open</button>')
}
```

When i inspect the button i see that the id is "opener_0" but when i click it is not working.
Any idea?
thanks!

Comment: could you include the code including the `array`

Comment: where is `i` pointer/index in the array from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).on('click', "#opener_0", (function() {
     $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

### Update

Your loop seems odd so try this.

```
var array = [1,2,3,4];
for (var r = 0; r < array.length; r++) {
    $('#list').append('<button id="opener_' + r + '">Open</button>')
}
```

#### [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xpWn2/)

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: sure! i dont know how to run jqueryUI on fiddle, but here it is:
http://jsfiddle.net/H6DM5/1/

Comment: The jsfidlle you created does nothing, if it doesn't work for you then it won't work for us either. Look at the one I created on the update answer

Answer (score 0):

The order of the javascript is very important.  If the for loop is after the click event binding, then there was no id of `opener_0` to bind to, so nothing happened. You would need to have the for loop that appends the button, to be before the binding of the click event.

Comment: i have the loop that appends the button before now, but still doing nothing